# Identify a 90's game with a car with a mounted cannon

Tags: identify-this-game, windows

Looking for a game from the 90's:

- You drive a brown buggy with a cannon mounted on top.
- 3rd person view in a 3D-like world. There were ramps, grass, water, walls...
- Single player campaign with a plot and levels to progress through; *not a racing game*.
- I think that the setting was post-apocalyptic. Some enemies were giants.
- In one stage you needed to switch cars and you were told "you can't take the fuzzy dice with you", referring to the fuzzy dice hung on the mirror.
- I played it around 1997-1999 on Win 95 or 98, so could have been released a bit earlier.
- VGA/SVGA colors.

Comment: Carmageddon or Carmageddon 2?

Comment: Post-apocalyptic but otherwise out and about in the real world? Not in some sort of future virtual reality, or confined to [in-game] arenas, or anything like that?

Comment: Interstate 76 perhaps?

Comment: @AlanB Those are racing games and the cars couldn't shoot. You also drove normal cars.

Comment: @Mavrik No, I know that one.

Comment: @Tommy It's not a full open world, there are different stages, in each one you can roam around freely (not linear). I don't think there was VR. The plot/story was set in the future, and it's not a pretty future.

Comment: I'd say Vigilante 8 only I don't think that was on PC.

Comment: @AlanB It's not that one.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're thinking of ***Vangers***, an overhead action-adventure by KD LAB who would later go on to make *Perimeter*, which has a similar graphical style and some references like 'spiral' transportation.

*Vangers* is I think like *Legacy of Kain* but with a living 'biological vehicle' theme and a silly sense of humour. You travel to different planets all with different themes and colours, and there's a gloomy arid setting to some locations which could be post apocalyptic. There are conversations with other vehicles, some vehicles are armed with weapons, and you transfer your consciousness from one vehicle to another to upgrade, so your quote about the dice seems possible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But this is a top-down view, not a 3rd person view. Unfortunately this is not it.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. :) At least it's one game we know it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be Quarantine?

Quarantine matches a lot of what you've mentioned there,

- You drive a yellow taxi, but is covered in blood in all the promotional artwork, and yellow+red = brown.
- It is 3rd person.
- It is a single-player game with levels and a plot to progress through.
- The setting is post-apocalytic.
- I don't remember that you needed to switch cars.
- Originally realeased in 1994, so you could have been playing it in 1997-1999.

[image: Quarantine]

[image]

Comment: Looks close at the very least. Will have to watch some gameplay later to see if it's that.